# How to free file pointed by url

Tags: ios, file, url

My question doesn't concern a particular situation but rather a global problem. 
How to free space pointed by url ? Sometimes we can't just use NSData, we have to write the data to files in order to use it, for instance when playing video with `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. In my current app, I download video and then let the user play them when he wants to so for now this is how I am doing it :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.mp4"];
[dataVideo writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
self.movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];
```

I write the data to a file and later

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController * movieView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
```

But how do I do if at one point in my application I want to delete the video (without user intervention) ?

Other example, I am using swagger.io to generate client code for my application. The methods for downloading are auto generated by swagger and I just have to use this method :

```
[defaultApi pdfDocumentNameGetWithCompletionBlock:@"myDoc.pdf" completionHandler:^(NSURL *output, NSError *error) {
}];
```

As you can see, this method gives me a URL towards the downloaded data, so unlike

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask = [self.mySession downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {  
}];
```

the space is not deallocated when you exit the completion handler even if you didn't do anything with the data. (I checked)
Can someone explain me how memory management works with local url ?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to know how to delete a file?

Comment: This isn't memory management, it is file management.

Comment: Yes, I guess it comes down to that, but I mean global explanation about how it works would be welcome. For instance, if I don't delete it, will the user find it somewhere in his video library ?

Comment: Updated the flag but there was no "file-management"